# Install Win7 after Ubuntu 13.10 (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows, windows-7

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and would like to set up a dual boot configuration with Windows 7.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would install window 7 normally. The thing is, windows installs its own boot loader instead of grub. Windows boot loader does not detect Ubuntu so you wouldn't be able to boot into it because you won't see it on startup.

To reinstall grub after you finish the windows installation, prepare an Ubuntu live USB, boot from it and and follow these instructions:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

or this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I guess that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general outline:

1.Make space for Windows 7

2.Install Windows 7

3.Reinstate GRUB

4.Mount the /boot partition

5.Install the boot loader

Step One

Open up GParted, and make sure that you have at least 20 GB available for Windows 7, either as a partition you can remove, or as unpartitioned space. If it's a partition, remove it from GRUB to make sure it doesn't break your Ubuntu install -- GParted will complain if anything bad is about to happen. Make note of current /boot device. If that doesn't show up there, make note of the / device. The device name is something like sda5.

Step Two

Install Windows 7 into the space you just made

Step Three

Load up from your Ubuntu live CD, and then run these commands.

If you DO NOT have a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /mnt
sudo rm -rf /boot
```

## Careful here, make sure YOU ARE USING THE LIVE CD. I tried,it works.

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot
```

If you have a SEPARATE /boot partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /boot
```

Step Four

Then continue with those commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-pc
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

## NOTE THAT THERE IS NO DIGIT

```
sudo umount /boot
```

And restart. It should work fine and boot both systems.